# problem of Error evaluating 'InitFcn' callback of MPC block (mask)?

Tags: matlab, simulink

how i diagnose this problem that i keep getting in simulate this model in simlink the error [HERE_FILES](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/114020-mpc-control-of-hybrid-energy-storage-systems?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_6_model%20predictive%20control%20storage) (i will attack the model ) :

```
Error evaluating 'InitFcn' callback of MPC block (mask) 'FB_MPC/FB_MPC Current Allocation & Charge Control System1/MPC Controller'. 
Callback string is 'impcblock_InitFcn'
Caused by:
Problems encountered when designing the default state estimator (Kalman filter) used by MPC.
The "kalman" command could not compute a convergent Kalman estimator for this combination of plant, disturbance and noise models.
To remedy the problem:
(1) Make sure that the plant model has minimal realization.
(2) Change disturbance and noise models such that all the states are observable.
```

Comment: Any experienced can answer me please or guide me ?